# Al ver los valores en tiempo de ejecución se muestra "Error interno en el compilador C#", y no el valor de variable durante depuración

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

**Datos técnicos:** Windows 10 x64, Visual Studio 2017, .NET Framework 4.5.

**El problema:** La solución está compuesta por varios proyectos, el principal en ASP .NET MVC, manda a llamar a través de un hilo a otro proyecto, pero al depurar, no puedo ver el valor de las variables del segundo proyecto, sino hasta que termina y retorna los valores al controlador de ASP, en su lugar muestra siempre el texto "Error interno en el compilador C#".

**Intentos para solucionarlo:** Ya intente volver a aagregar las referencias al proyecto, y no a las dll, además, recompile cada proyecto por separado y limpiar claro, también en Opciones de depuración active distintas opciones y en las opciones de los proyectos, todas apuntan al mismo Framework.

**Ejemplo:**[image: Ejemplo del error]

**Configuración de depuración:**[image: Parte 1 de configuración]
[image: Parte 2 de configuración]

Comment: hola @Alex Lz probaste habilitando Usar Modo de compatibilidad administrado? veo que está deshabilitada la opción pero es porque seguro estás en ejecución, te recomiendo probar con eso. Avisame si no se soluciona.

Comment: Efectivamente, solo era de habilitar esa opción, ya funciona, gracias

Comment: ahí agregué esto como respuesta si te parece bien marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me suele ocurrir lo mismo y lo soluciono habilitando `Usar modo de compatibilidad administrado`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]